# Moving Sage 200 App and DB Servers

Tags: application, consolidation

I've tried Sage's Community pages and i'm struggling to find an answer to what i'd like to believe is a common scenario.

We need to move our Sage App installation and DB to new servers as part of a data centre move / consolidation exercise.

I've spoken to our parners who have advised me that it isn't as straight forward as a backup/restore of the db and fresh installation of the app set-up as the previous server name is hard coded somewhere?

Has anybody had to do this before?

Regards

Comment: Do you have a support contract with Sage?

Comment: Our support contact has informed me that this would be chargeable, and sage will not entertain us directly